# Itext Unbalanced begin/end text operators

Tags: java, itext

I am getting below exception though I am doing begin and close.Not sure if its because of in exception block I am not closing.

```
ERROR xyz.A  - execute() error closing OutputStreamWriter.    [source:]
    java.io.IOException: com.lowagie.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end text operators.
            at PDFOutputWriter.close(PDFOutputWriter.java:91)
            at xyz.A.execute_aroundBody0(A.java:319)
          org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
```

The below code is throwing this exception.

```
  public void addPageNumber(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        cb.saveState();
        String text = writer.getCurrentPageNumber() - pageOffset + " - " + timeStamp;
        float textBase = document.bottom() - 20;
        cb.beginText();
        try {
            cb.setFontAndSize( BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252,
                false), 12);

        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cb.setTextMatrix(document.left(), textBase);
        cb.showText(text);
        cb.endText();
        cb.restoreState();
        previousPage = writer.getCurrentPageNumber();
    }



<groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.lowagie</artifactId>
<itext.version>2.1.7</itext.version>


 <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
 <version>5.5.8</version>
```

Comment: Two things: 1) share a pdf that reproduces the exception 2) try to reproduce with iText 5.5.10, because you are using a version of iText that is older than 2009.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 2.1.7 is `com.lowagie`, 5.x.x is `com.itextpdf`.

Comment: sorry added in question

Comment: I think this code uses com.itextpdf

Comment: No, it doesn't. The exception clearly says `com.lowagie`, which is up to version 2.1.7, which is older than 2009. Trust me, I know this, I work for iText Software and I've been responsible for the release process the last two years.

Comment: I agree with Amedee: you are definitely not using iText 5. Look at my name if you doubt my authority on this topic. I'm the one who put the `lowagie` in `com.lowagie`. This being said, I looked at your code and I don’t see anything in `addPageNumber()` that can cause the exception you mention. I'd only make one change: I'd create the `BaseFont` outside of this method, because that `createFont()` and that `try`/`catch` are costing you CPU every time you call that method.

Comment: Thank you both I will try that.Thanks for help.@BrunoLowagie.I have read lot of your reply regarding same topic.